# Split a string into smaller strings and not arrays

Tags: php, string, split

need a little help with a small issue of string splitting.

I'm trying to split a serial number into two, do some calculations on the second half and join it back to the first half. My problem is the second half starts with two zeros and PHP removes the leading zeros.

I think keeping the variables as strings will keep the zeros but I can't seem to find a way to split the serial number into smaller strings, all the methods I try split them into an array. Here is a part of my code;

```
$info1 = nkw549blc003i00021; //this is the serial number.
```

I want to split `$info1` into;

```
$number1 = nkw549blc003i0

$number2 = 0021
```

then use  `for loop` on `$number2` like

```
$num = 1;
for ($num=1; $num < $unitsquantity[$key] ; $num++) {
  $sum = $number2+$num;
  $final=$number1.$sum;
  echo "$final<br>";
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can always create strings from array keys if you have arrays as your split operation result. Becides, what are the rules that define how you need to split the serial?

Comment: The problem is that you're applying a mathematical operation `+` on the number, which turns it into a number, which doesn't have leading zeros. It doesn't matter whether that happens in separate variables or arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are array chars, so you can get each char of them by iterating through their length

```
define('SERIAL_NUM_LEN', 4);
$info1 = 'nkw549blc003i00021';
$number1 = ''; $number2 = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($info1)-SERIAL_NUM_LEN; $i++) {
    $number1 .= $info1[$i];
}
for ($i = strlen($info1)-SERIAL_NUM_LEN; $i < strlen($info1); $i++) {
    $number2 .= $info1[$i];
}

var_dump($number1, $number2);
```

Output:

```
string 'nkw549blc003i0' (length=14)

string '0021' (length=4)
```

This way you can skip whichever chars from the string you want if you want to build totally different string. Or add chars in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

```
$info1 = 'nkw549blc003i00021';

$number1 = substr($info1, 0, -4);
$number2 = sprintf('%1$04d', substr($info1, -4, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string will always be 4 chars long, you can use [str_pad](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
for ($num=1; $num < $unitsquantity[$key] ; $num++) {
  echo $number1 . str_pad($number2+$num, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```